# Как удалить дефолтные селекторы в woocommerce quantity-input?

Tags: woocommerce

Я хочу удалить стрелки, выделенные красным (они появляются при наведении на количество) и оставить только количество товара и +/- для увеличения/уменьшения количества товара.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой код у меня:

`<div class="quantity">
<input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
<input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
<input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>`

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. php: Вам нужно либо изменить тип инпута с number на text - это уберет стрелки, но это может вызывать некоторые проблемы с скриптами в последующем. В частности проблемы будут вызваны в скриптах woocommerce, которые отвечают за обработку кол-ва. Поэтому не уверен что этот вариант подойдет.
2. css:

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, работает!

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, вы можете отметить его как верный)